# iText, FileNotFoundException when adding image to pdf

Tags: android, image, pdf, itext

I am trying to add an image to my pdf using iText and when following the iTexts documentation on this its just simply telling me to do this:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance("res/drawable/toplogos.png");
document.add(img);
```

But I am getting FileNotFoundException. Why is that? The file is in the drawable folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, hope this will help you

```
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toplogos)
 BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
 Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();  
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
 Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
 document.add(image);
```

Comment: I dont know really iText has its own way of handle images and when reading The example on iText site this is the only thing to do but apperently not. Here is how they do it http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=70

Comment: if you wan to add a image from external card you can use that, but in the case of res you need to do some thing like this

Comment: OK. I will try it out